# differences between Visual Studio version 15.0 and 15.x

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Since the very beginning of the release of Visual Studio 2017, it seems there has been [two differentiated branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2017):
- 15.0
- 15.x

In the above link you can see that 15.0.0 and 15.1 Preview 1 were released the same day, and then there were updates for 15.0 and 15.x.  At the date of this question, latest versions are 15.0.21 and 15.9.11

What are the differences between these two development branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general Microsoft offers a dual support model for most of these tools:

- Stay on RTM/RTW. Basically the 15.0.x version. This version will receive hotfixes, but no feature improvements and is a Long-Term-Support version. This version is generally only available through Visual Studio subscriptions and can only be downloaded from https://my.visualstudio.com.
- Stay on the latest version. Basically the 15.x.x version. This version will receive hotfixes and feature updates at a regular interval until the next major version (2019) is released. Support is normally only given on the latest update version, so if you have issues, you're likely going to be asked to upgrade to the latest 15.x.x version to see if the issue persists.

The same applies to Azure DevOps Server / Team Foundation Server.

- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.9.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.9).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.8.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.8).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.7.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.7).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.6.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.6).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.5.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.4.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.4).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.3.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.3).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.2.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.2).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.1.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.1).
- [Release notes for Visual Studio 2017 15.0.x can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0).

In general you get more features, improvements and fixes in the 15.x.x version. But you may have to upgrade your solution from time to time to stay current with the tooling.

You get fewer impacting changes and a longer support window by staying on 15.0.x.